# Get Image Information From Paint.NET

Tags: windows, paint.net

How can I view detailed information (width, height, bit depth, etc) of an image I have loaded in Paint.net?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  There doesn't seem to be a way to do that in Paint.net.  If you don't mind popping out to use Windows Explorer: open the file's properties, go to the Summary tab and click the Advanced button if you can see it.  That should show what you want.  Yes, I realize that this doesn't answer your question.  But a workaround is the next best thing, right?

Answer (score 0):

The image height and width is displayed at the bottom right of the status bar, next to the current cursor location.

[image]